# Including logic in a numerical function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I think / hope there is a simple answer to this question, but it's alluding me thus far I'm afraid.

I want to implement the following sort of function, including logic:

```
def my_func(x):
    if x < 5:
        return 2
    else:
        return 2*x
```

So when an array of the form: my_x = np.arange(1,10,1) is passed to it:

```
y = my_func(my_x)
```

The result is:
    y = [2, 2, 2, 2, 10, 12, 14, 18]

I guess this could be done with a for loop in the function to append the result of each element back on to some form of RESULT array, but this seems a bit clunky.

Is there a better way please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know that your function will be passed a numpy array, you can write it using `numpy` functions to do what you want in a vectorized fashion:

```
def my_np_func(x):
    return np.where(x<5, 2, 2*x)
```

You could also vectorize your original function and apply that:

```
np.vectorize(my_func)(x)
```

But that will probably be slower since the function will be called many times instead of just once.

Comment: +1 exactly what `np.where` is for.  the solution with np.vectorize is not good, because it is a "fake" vectorize (does not actually run in parallel, just loops)

Comment: Note that if you *don't* pass an array, or you pass an array scalar, `where` will return a 0D array. These may cause a few surprises, though hopefully not too much worse than the few surprises array scalars already cause.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`np.select`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
In [6]: condlist = [my_x < 5, my_x >= 5]

In [7]: choicelist = [2, 2*my_x]

In [8]: np.select(condlist, choicelist)
Out[8]: array([ 2,  2,  2,  2, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18])
```

@BrenBarn's solution is great, but `np.select` seems much more general as you can have multiple conditions as well as default values. If you can frame your solution as a single condition, definitely use `np.where` as it is faster.